# Sonar is throwing an error Null Pointer Exception should not be caught and how can i fix it?

Tags: java

Sonar qube is giving this error in aem6.5 -- NullPointerException should not be catch

```
@PostConstruct
protected void init() {
   try{
      pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
      requestedPage = pageManager.getPage(rootvalue);
      Iterator<Page> siblingPages = requestedPage.listChildren();

      while (siblingPages.hasNext()) {
         Page siblingPage = siblingPages.next();
         if (siblingPage.getProperties().get("hideInNav") == null)
            siblingItems.add(siblingPage);
      }
   } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
      log.error("NullPointerException exception occured in SideNavigation " + exception.getMessage());
   }
}
```

can some one help me on this.

```
@PostConstruct
protected void init() {
   if(resourceResolver!=null){
      pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
      assert pageManager != null;
      requestedPage = pageManager.getPage(rootvalue);
      Iterator<Page> siblingPages = requestedPage.listChildren();

      while (siblingPages.hasNext()) {
         Page siblingPage = siblingPages.next();
         if (siblingPage.getProperties().get("hideInNav") == null)
            siblingItems.add(siblingPage);
      }
   } else {
      log.error("exception occurred in SideNavigation ");
   }
}
```

How can we fix this sonar qube error?

Comment: Isn't the issue already fixed in the second snippet? You no longer catch the exception. As to how to avoid it: check everything that *could* be `null` before accessing it, that way you don't get NPEs.

Answer (score 0):

```
  requestedPage = pageManager.getPage(rootvalue);
  assert requestedPage != null;
  Iterator<Page> siblingPages = requestedPage.listChildren();
```

suggest check this **requestedPage** before **listChildren** as well